# Wordpress - Prevent generating image thumbs size

Tags: wordpress, hook-wordpress

I need to **completely** avoid generating this thumbnail size: ‘user_thumb’ – 45×45

**Update-2**: this image size is set by the Theme I am using. Then, image size I need to disable is not listed at Settings -> Media

I think this function in my_functions.php will do the job:

**Am I right? Will this work?**

**Update-1:** Can set the priority of this code to overwrite any other code in the theme and plugins?

```
function shapeSpace_disable_user_thumbs($sizes) {
unset($sizes[‘user_thumb’]); // disable 45×45 size
return $sizes;
}
add_action(‘intermediate_image_sizes_advanced’, ‘shapeSpace_disable_user_thumbs’);
```

Regards,

Answer (score -1):

You can follow these steps for the same :

Step 1: In Admin Panel Go to Settings -> Media.

Step 2: Now Uncheck (Crop thumbnail) If it's Checked.

Step 3: Set at Thumbnail size, Medium size, and Large size the Width and Height to 0.

This will help you in the same.

Comment: I only see there the three Image sizes of the core: Thumbnail size, Medium size and and Large size. I need to unset Image sizes which are added by the theme.

Comment: You can set the height and width 0 for  Thumbnail size, Medium size, and Large one.

Comment: the thumbnail size I need to unset is not there.

Comment: These are the wordpress default ones.